# Standard deviation function in Python on one line

Tags: python, lambda

I am to write a function for standard deviation on one line. I can only use math, lambdas, len.

The estimated result is, as my assignment says, 288.37475617675.

Non-one line code gives me an answer slightly different, thus, wrong.

```
import math

aList = [7, 12, 17, 22, 27, 32, 37, 42, 47, 52, 57, 62, 67, 72, 77, 82, 87, 92, 97, 100, 105, 110, 115, 120, 125, 130, 135, 140, 145, 150, 155, 160, 165, 170, 175, 180, 185, 190, 195, 200, 205, 210, 215, 220, 225, 230, 235, 240, 245, 250, 255, 260, 265, 270, 275, 280, 285, 290, 295, 300, 305, 310, 315, 320, 325, 330, 335, 340, 345, 350, 355, 360, 365, 370, 375, 380, 385, 390, 395, 400, 405, 410, 415, 420, 425, 430, 435, 440, 445, 450, 455, 460, 465, 470, 475, 480, 485, 490, 495, 500, 505, 510, 515, 520, 525, 530, 535, 540, 545, 550, 555, 560, 565, 570, 575, 580, 585, 590, 595, 600, 605, 610, 615, 620, 625, 630, 635, 640, 645, 650, 655, 660, 665, 670, 675, 680, 685, 690, 695, 700, 705, 710, 715, 720, 725, 730, 735, 740, 745, 750, 755, 760, 765, 770, 775, 780, 785, 790, 795, 800, 805, 810, 815, 820, 825, 830, 835, 840, 845, 850, 855, 860, 865, 870, 875, 880, 885, 890, 895, 900, 905, 910, 915, 920, 925, 930, 935, 940, 945, 950, 955, 960, 965, 970, 975, 980, 985, 990, 995, 1000]
mean = sum(aList)/(len(aList)-1)
def ok(x):
  return (x - mean)**2
print(math.sqrt(sum(list(map(ok, aList)))/(len(aList))))
#or
mean = sum(aList)/len(aList)
def ok(x):
  return (x - mean)**2
print(math.sqrt(sum(map(ok, aList))/(len(aList))))
```

One-line code for

```
math.sqrt(sum(list(map(lambda x: x - sum(aList)/len(aList)**2, aList)))/len(aList - 1)
```

anyways gives me math domain error.

What is wrong with my function and how do I get the estimated result?
Why does this domain error occur and how do I fix it?

Comment: Welcome to SO! This code is difficult to read. What's wrong with breaking it out into intermediate variables and avoiding cleverness? `ok` is a pretty poor function name... basically pretending `map` doesn't exist would probably improve the code substantially.

Comment: If you reassign every substatement of the one-liner into its own variable, the interpreter will give you the line from which the error comes from.

Comment: @ggorlen Hi, thank you! My assignment says everything should be on one line. Sorry about ok, what I meant is "okay to work with". What do you mean pretending map doesn't exist?

Comment: @BłażejMichalik not on one line it works (bit gives wrong answer) and there is no math error

Comment: That's unfortunate. `map` is leading you to (in my opinion) very unreadable code, so I'm advocating not using it at all here. If you _have_ to do it in one line (are schools teaching code golf now?) try a list comprehension over map, 9 times out of 10. In real life, you'd probably use [this](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.std.html).

Comment: @erm823ry the only way to get math domain error in that one-liner is if your `math.sqrt` is given a negative value. Check why your sum has a negative value, and you'll find where the problem is.

Comment: I think they're trying to get us to be more comfortable with F# when the time comes to use it

Comment: Good luck--I don't know anything about F#. Well, `std = sqrt(mean(abs(x - mean(x))**2))` is given in the link above, so all you have to do is write the `mean` function and you're done. If you have to do it in one line, then replace the calls to `mean` with code that computes the mean, e.g. `sum(x) / len(x)`. Maybe there is a clever way to avoid the repetition mathematically but I wouldn't know.

Answer (score 0):

seems little mistake with brackets and calculating length.

`math.sqrt(sum(list(map(lambda x: (x - sum(aList)/len(aList))**2, aList)))/len(aList))` works well.

Comment: thank you! do you have any idea about the estimated result maybe? my function and your answer both give 288.37413875033945 when it should be 288.37475617675

Comment: `numpy.std` also gives 288.3741387503394